# Stop IntelliJ Idea autocompletion from removing qualifying classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In a project of mine, we use default inner classnames and qualify them by their parent class like so:

```java
Customer.Row
Product.Row
Supplier.Row
```

If I try to add a call to a row's method using autocompletion, IntelliJ will strip away the qualifying class and auto-import the Row, which I don't want to happen:

```java
import what.ever.Supplier.Row;
...
Row.doSomething();
```

I just want

```java
Supplier.Row.doSomething();
```

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend two things.

- Modify your settings in Preferences > Editor > General > Auto Import
- Start with the parent class such as: Supplier.Row. then let it auto complete.